# Adding left and right borders to slick slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a slick slider and i am trying to add a dashed border to the left and right of the content.

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/4iejdteLKFUo8ECQLpuh?p=preview

I have 2 issues:

1. The right border is not showing
2. There is not enough padding between the border and the text

How can i fix the above?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="grid-wrap">
      <div class="grid-col one-eighth">
        <div class="your-class">
          <div class="text-box">test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1</div>
          <div class="text-box">test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2</div>
          <div class="text-box">test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3</div>
          <div class="text-box">test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.text-box {
    border-left: 1px dashed white;
    border-right: 1px dashed white; 
}
```

Image of border right issue:

[image: border right issue 1]

Comment: It is appearing you can't see it because it is white colored http://jsfiddle.net/xupfg8ba/

Comment: @Akshay - thanks, but please look at my plunker. i have a blue background and cant see the white border of test2... Also, as my second white, the padding is an issue. I am looking for a some padding between the border and the text.

Comment: I can see the white border and i think this solves your padding issue http://plnkr.co/edit/PntID9C4XYc5mjspZ6Z6?p=preview

Comment: @Akshay - please see the updated screenshot of the borer right issue

Comment: That is because the border is hidden if you increase the width of plunker you can see it http://i.imgur.com/7CpBtWD.jpg

Comment: @Akshay - thanks, im not sure if increasing the width is the right answer. this is supposed to be a repsonive slider so the borders should show with having to adjust the width.

Answer (score 1):

I corrected your plunk. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/alurwdlyicnLw3BBN1VQ?p=preview

I simply added a padding to the .text-box class

```
.text-box {
  border-left: 1px dashed white;
  border-right: 1px dashed white;
  padding: 30px;
 }
```

I also changed the grid-wrap width to 70% + 6px (all borders combined)

```
.grid-wrap {
  width: calc(70% + 6px);
}
```

Like this you are able to change the padding and you are able to see all borders. Keep in mind that if you change the border width you also must change the + xp.

Comment: i think theres an issue, if you look at the right border of test1, its thinker than the left border of test1.... I think the left border of test2 is being applied to the right of test1

Comment: Between the different text-boxes the border is 2px since there are 2 borders there. One from the left box and one from the right box. To solve that you would have to completely rearrange the css of the text-boxes.